# Как задать CSS-параметр классу если DOM-структура страницы содержит определенный класс?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Как задать CSS-параметр классу если DOM-структура страницы содержит определенный класс?
Например, на странице есть хоть один блок с классом `showme`, то для класса `showit` будет приписано значение display: block !important;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если там совсем хитрая разметка и стандартные CSS-селекторы не прокатывают, технически, это можно сделать так:

```js
setTimeout( addChangesCSS, 1000 );

function addChangesCSS(){
  let search = ["bubu", "red"];
  
  search = search.filter( className => document.querySelector('.' + className) )
                 .map( className => "js-found-" + className );
  
  document.body.className += ( " " + search.join(" ") );
}
```

```css
.showit { display: none; }

.green { color: green; }

/* всё заранее прописано в CSS, js только ищет и добавляет нужные классы на body */
.js-found-red .green { color: red; }
.js-found-bubu .showit { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="showit">
  show...
  <div class="bubu">bubu</div>
</div>

<div class="green">
  <div class="red">bubu</div>
  red
</div>
```

Но если в коде появилось такое, вероятно что-то идет не так!)

Comment: Подскажите, `  let search = ["bubu", "red"];` ищет на странице CSS-классы?

Comment: @QuickBrownFox Это список классов, которые надо искать) Ищет `document.querySelector('.' + className)` — возвращает элемент, если найдет, или null. Найденный элемент в логическом контексте → true, а null → false. В зависимости от этого - filter убирает или оставляет название класса в массиве. К оставшимся классам `map` приклеивает `js-found-` и все эти классы в конце добавляются на body.